# legal recourse against a company with no contact information

Tags: united-states, commerce

I have an online account with a company that provides no contact information. The company is charging me for services I don't want and is providing no way for me to cancel the services or get in touch with it. I could cancel the credit card that the company has on file but the company also holds property of mine (it is the registrar of my domain name) and I don't want to lose it. I am at the point where I am looking for legal solutions to this problem as I don't see any alternative.

Is there any legal requirement in the US for a company to provide customers a means to dispute charges or otherwise contact it? Is there any legal recourse I can take in this situation?

Comment: Can you transfer the domain to another servicer?

Comment: @RonBeyer Right now I can't even log into my account. Without any means to contact the company, I can't recover my account.

Comment: What company is this? There has to be registration information, you can try looking up the ICANN information for the sites domain, for example [from here](http://www.register.com/whois.rcmx) that may have contact emails and phone numbers.

Comment: @RonBeyer I would prefer not to name and shame at this point. I did look up the whois information on the domain name and it has no contact information. `gethuman.com` lists an email address but I received no reply. I received no reply from the company's sales email address. I suppose there might be a physical address in the business registration, but would probably need legal assistance to look that up.

Comment: Ask your credit card company; they will have contact info and a phone number for the company. Tell them the issues you are having, but you don't have to ask  them to stop the charge on the one service you want to cancel.

Comment: You could also file a complaint against the registrar over their service issues and your inability to contact them: https://www.icann.org/complaints-office

Comment: How are they "holding" your domain name?  Is it registered (with a domain registrar) to them or to you?  Please, clarify that in your question.  The answers to you question are very different depending on which one of those it is.

Answer (score 2):

Can you find their details here: https://www.icann.org/registrar-reports/accredited-list.html?

There's a link referring to 2009 RAA in the 3rd paragraph of the page. It looks like that's the deal that the Registrar needs to sign up to to be a Registrar in the first place.

Not making any suggestions here... their behaviour could be licence threatening.